# Error Message from Powershell Script mail to EmailAddress

Tags: email, powershell, send, mailmessage

I have constructed an script for our Dataloader in Salesforce:

```
   **# The Function for the Check Error File** 

    function CheckErrorFile {

    Param ([string]$perrorfilepath)

    $csvlines = (Get-Content $perrorfilepath | Measure-Object -line).Lines

    # header is always 1 row so we look for > 1 rows
    if ($csvlines -gt 1)
    {
        $errorCount = $csvLines - 1
        $errorMessage = [string]::Format("** errors ** {0} failed rows in {1}", $errorCount, $perrorfilepath)
        # this will print red error message but not stop execution
        write-error $errorMessage
    }

}

**# set up locations/variables for data loader**
$dataloader = "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\process.bat"
$dlconfig = "U:\Projekte\Salesforce\Dataloader-Test-Infor-Files\Example-Migration-SF-Test\DataLoaderConfig"
set-location  "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin"
$dlLogFolder = "U:\Projekte\Salesforce\Dataloader-Test-Infor-Files\Example-Migration-SF-Test\Logs\" 
**# execute the data loader**

& $dataloader $dlconfig testsf-delete

**# check for errors in the error.csv file**
CheckErrorFile ("{0}error_testsf.csv" -f $dlLogFolder)
```

So far so good it think

But what i want to is that the Error Code which comes Back from CheckErrorFile Command should sent to an Email Address.

So i  had think about 2 Considerations:

1. when if error sent to mail
2. pack the error output in a variable and sent to mail adress

But i'm not so good at Powershell that i know how i have to integrate this in my script.

I found a site with an send trigger when a eventlog has changed but I'm not sure if i can use this for my purposes and how i have to integrate this:

[Powershell Email when Eventlog is Changed](http://sharepointjack.com/2013/powershell-to-send-an-email-when-something-happens-in-the-event-log/)

May someone could help

thnks

Comment: So you are just asking how to send a mail in PowerShell? There should be oodles of examples here already about that. The only thing I would change in your function is change the `write-error` to `write-output` as it would be easier to catch it in one of the standard streams.

Comment: Yes i know   these examples but I dont know how i have to implement it in my script ...

Comment: Look at the examples here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+send-mailmessage and all you have to do is capture proper output from your function as a body